# How to add data that separated with coma to database

Tags: php, mysql, implode

i want to insert my data to database. i have data that separated with commas.

i try like this but look like something wrong.

```
$rand_post = ["3001182708", "3001182713", "3001183215"]; 
$id_post = '123456';

$prep = array();
foreach($rand_post as $v ) {
    $prep[] = "($id_post, $v)";
}
print_r($prep);
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tes (`id_post`,`datas`) VALUES " . implode(', ', $prep));
$res = $sth->execute($prep);
```

i want to insert my data like this

```
id_post            rand_post
============       ================
123456             3001182708
123456             3001182713
123456             3001183215
```

Comment: During prepare statement, you pass *?* instead of the `$prep` array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close but instead of gluing the strings use the power of prepared statements. You **prepare** the query and then in the loop you execute it with different params. Can be named as well.

```
$rand_post = ["3001182708", "3001182713", "3001183215"]; 
$id_post = '123456';

$prep = array();
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tes (`id_post`,`datas`) VALUES (?, ?)");

foreach($rand_post as $v ) {
    $sth->execute(array($id_post, $v));
}
```

You can find more information [here](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: Bad practice. you should avoid queries inside loops.

Comment: @MaratBadykov it isn't a bad practice to execute prepared statement inside the loop. It's different than executing query itself. Don't bring confusion to the OP.

Comment: In general, it's usually better performance-wise to do bulk or batch queries than queries in a loop, since you can save round trip calls to the DB.

Comment: @MaratBadykov it'd make difference if the dataset was really big.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$rand_post = ["3001182708", "3001182713", "3001183215"]; 
$id_post = '123456';

$prep = array();
foreach($rand_post as $v ) {
    $prep[] = "($id_post, $v)";
}

$dataToInsert = implode(', ', $prep);
$sth = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tes VALUES " . $dataToInsert);
$res = $sth->execute($prep);
```

Comment: Sorry, i was wrong with syntax. I updated answer, pls test

Comment: Using answer from Robert is bad practice, you shoul avoid queries inside loops.

Comment: @MaratBadykov it's better than gluing strings instead of using prepared statements, and it's quite common practice. The query is prepared on db side and what it actually does is binding the parameters to this prepared query. For sure it's better solution than the one that you propose. Cheers .